# AWS cloudwatch CPU Utilization doesn't match actual usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage, amazon-cloudwatch

1. I have setup a AWS CloudWatch alarm: CPU utilization > 90 %: https://www.screencast.com/t/BPs3hlY2hEZ
2. I have added the alarm / CPU % utilization metric to a dashboard: https://content.screencast.com/users/MartinBakDK/folders/Jing/media/5c01c414-95d7-4a20-ab7d-e0a6c9debc01/2020-05-20_2158.png

I do know - that the metric shows a 5 min average - But for more than 1 hour now the actual CPU usage of my EC2 instance has been 100% (So it should show 100% as well):
https://www.screencast.com/t/BvITivn0ff

Because CloudWatch only reg. 20% and not the actual 100% => CloudWatch is useless as a monitoring-system.

Can this really be true? Please tell me what is going on and how AWS can provide such a "service".

Comment: Hi is this a burstable instance?

Comment: It is a AWS EC2 t3.small instance (2 cpu + 2 gb memory). It looks like it is burstable as well yes: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/
What does this mean for CloudWatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at CpuCreditBalance metric. If this is at 0 your CPU will be capped at a fixed percentage (this is why you see the straight line).

Your host sees itself as 100% because it cannot use anymore CPU.

All T instances are burstable, so once they’re depleted the CPU is capped for performance. You can either change instance type or enable unlimited credits (there will be additional cost).

Further reading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits.html

Comment: The latest 2 weeks look like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/l3YuetKdCWiM - is that what you are ref. to? I was not aware that each instance had a CPU credit-limit. So I should understand this as a quote ...like you have in your cell-phone subscription? If use too much data - suddenly the download-speed will be limited to an absolute minimum? What would you suggest me to do of the two options? What do you think is the best solution - it should like you have experience with it?

Comment: Hi, yes that reached 0. Set an alarm on the balance being 0 as this will be when you have performance cap. If this doesn’t deplete often you could add unlimited burst.

Comment: My t3.small cost 0.0392 usd/hour. It states also that t-instances: $0.096 per vCPU-Hour for Windows. So when it burst it cost 0.0392 usd/hour + (2 x 0.096 usd/hour) - right (because it list it has 2 vcpu)? But the weird part is - that t3 instances are already launched in "unlimited" mode according to this: https://www.screencast.com/t/YS8gBU9x so again --> why do I still have CPU-credits-issues/limits then - AWS should just charge me right and then let use all the cpu I want?

Comment: Further: When I under "EC2 instances" right-click --> Instance settings --> Change T2/T3 unlimited --> I get this popup: https://www.screencast.com/t/UP3KHm6i so according to this it conflicts with AWS own documentation - which states it pér default already is launched in "unlimited mode". But at least it explains all my issues :-D And I now fully understand the dynamics of all this :-D I have been working with AWS since 2014 and I have never been aware of these instance-types have a so-called CPU-quote-limit.

Comment: Further: 2.5 hour ago I enabled "Unlimited burstable mode" for my EC2 t3.small instance...I expected that it would dramatically change the CPU-Power of the instance ...But almost nothing happened...The CPU usage is still between 50%-100% (before closer to 100% most of the time)...But the CloudWatch still shows static 20% CPU usage + the metric for CPU-credit- balance has risen from 0.7 to almost 1.0 ...when the server is full of power/credits the normal CPU usage is 10-30%...So to me it seems like this "Burstable unlimited mode" doesn't do much in reality... please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: I found this in the AWS DOCS: https://www.screencast.com/t/QoOHhnaz3e6 which confirms why CloudWatch shows static 20%... But after I enabled "Unlimited mode" it should allow me to use 100% CPU again...But it simply doesn't... :-( My only solution left now - is to upgrade to a larger and none-burstable instance like m5.large or c5.large.

Comment: Try restarting with the unlimited burstable first

Comment: I just did and it just went from this: https://www.screencast.com/t/qoEiWSZzpf4v to this https://www.screencast.com/t/lOSD4Spn6u LOL! It is bursting in the wrong direction :-D But at least the CPU usage metric went from 20% to over 50% https://www.screencast.com/t/ZmeDSbo9G

Comment: That looks a bit better. Technically when you restart the instance it should reset your credit balance to 0

Comment: Can you tell how exactly I should understand this chart: https://www.screencast.com/t/Hk0NM12Ipz0 No matter what time-range and period I select it always shows 7 CPU Credits Used... So what is the actual usage per hour (for example)? Btw. the CPU credit balance now looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/NrAMehGCwlGH

Comment: I still don't understand how many credits my app. actually uses in unlimited mode? But AWS do charge me the expected: 0.096 usd/pér hour: https://www.screencast.com/t/Z3lLqIUBc It is a way to expensive solution - especially when only using a t3.small instance... the "unlimited mode" cost the same no matter the instance-type! So be aware.

Comment: Yes, so this is why burstable are more preferable for occasional burst based workloads such as servers running scripts. For dedicated general purpose you'd look at M

Comment: I'm now running an EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 m5.large instance (not burstable instance!) + I have setup monitoring of CPU + MEMORY - and to my big surprise the numbers don't match again :-(( https://www.screencast.com/t/o1nAnOFjVZW